# Sending push using parse.com Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a problem with sending a push notification from Cloud Code. I want to send Push after saving an `AlertPoint` object. My code looks like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("AlertPoint", function(request) {
    Parse.Push.send({
        data: {
            alert: "Test push."
        }
    }, {
        success: function() {
            //push successsful
            }, 
        error: function(error) {
            //Handle error
            throw "Got an error" + error.code + " : " + error.message;
        }
    });
});
```

But the push is not sent and I get an error:

```
Result: Uncaught Got an error115 : Missing the push channels.
```

I would like to send the push to all registered users and I've seen code examples in which the push was sent without setting channels. What am I doing wrong and how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe all users in a blank channel and set the push to broadcast the message to this blank channel too.